# How many times will "Hello World" be printed?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("Hello World");
```

I think the answer should be n(n)! because the outer loop executes n times and the inner loop (n)! times.

Comment: If you run it you will get your answer. What is the question ?

Comment: `I think the answer should be`...what's stopping you from verifying it?

Comment: Why don't you run and see?

Comment: The question is in the heading.

Comment: I am trying to solve it theoretically without running it.

Comment: Then take a pen and run it "mentally" you will understand how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the math wrong.

The answer would be 1+2+3+4+ ... upto n-1

and not 1*2*3 ... n

Answer (score 2):

Well you can introduce a counter to be sure

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        printf("Hello World");
        counter  ++;
    }
```

Or take a pen :

```
i = 1  j = 0  Hello World
i = 2  j = 0  Hello World
       j = 1  Hello World
i = 3  j = 0  Hello World
       j = 1  Hello World
       j = 2  Hello World
i = 4  j = 0  Hello World
       j = 1  Hello World
       j = 2  Hello World
       j = 3  Hello World
[...]
```

And you can see a pattern... 1 + 2 + 3 + ... ?